# How to redraw an ExpandableList within one of its Adapters functions?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have an android application that has an ExpandableList, in its Adapters `getChildView(int,int,boolean,View,ViewGroup)` I want to redraw the ExpandableList if some conditions were true, what should I do?

Comment: Try to call `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to redraw the `ExpandableList` in its adapter, i guess it will make the list recursive and make a huge memory consumption, what's your reason to do so?

Comment: @esentsov : call this function for which object?

Comment: @user2652394 I want that when a button in the expandableList is clicked, the expandableList redraw

Comment: You means a row can control a whole expandable list view? That is not a good way to go. However, if you must do so, write a listener for you r adapter and it should call refresh when the condition match. Note: `notifydatasetchanged()` is for refreshing.

Comment: for `adapter` (if you use `BaseAdapter` or its subclasses).

Comment: @esentsov , I've used ExpanableListAdapter, it seems that it doesn't have the `notifydatasetchanged()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer but it is **NOT** recommended:

This is your Acitivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapterListener{
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView1;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        expandableListView1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        expandableListView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void doRefresh() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

This is your Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    public interface MyAdapterListener{
        public void doRefresh();
    }

    private MyAdapterListener listener;

    public MyAdapter(MyAdapterListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(some condition is true and you want to refresh the list view){
            listener.doRefresh();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've extended `ExpandableListAdapter` and it doesn't have `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: As far as I know there is NO class called `ExpandableListAdapter`, is that your own class?

Comment: your_expandable_list_view.invalidateViews() should do the work.